# Javascript slider value to be dependant on select option to populate price field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script and some HTML, before I added in the option (Select) box it worked fine. 
I need the slider to show the value of the slider, and in the field under the price in BTC for the contract, however the BTC price also needs to update dependant on the select option changing the value dependant contract length
If someone could help me out that would be great!

Here is my code snippet:

```js
var rangeSlider = function() {
  var slider = $('.range-slider'),
    range = $('.range-slider__range'),
    value = $('.range-slider__value');

  var slider = $(".month_select: selected").value();;

  if (slider == 1) {
    month = 1 m;
  } else if (slider == 2) {
    month = 2 m;
  } else if (slider == 3) {
    month = 3 m;
  } else if (slider == 4) {
    month = 4 m;
  } else if (slider == 5) {
    month = 5 m;
  } else if (slider == 6) {
    month = 6 m;
  } else if (slider == 7) {
    month = 7 m;
  } else if (slider == 8) {
    month = 8 m;
  } else if (slider == 9) {
    month = 9 m;
  } else if (slider == 10) {
    month = 10 m;
  } else if (slider == 11) {
    month = 11 m;
  } else if (slider == 12) {
    month = 12 m;
  }

  var 1 m = "0.000003732";
  var 2 m = "0.000004732";
  var 3 m = "0.000005732";
  var 4 m = "0.000006732";
  var 5 m = "0.000007732";
  var 6 m = "0.000008732";
  var 7 m = "0.000009732";
  var 8 m = "0.000010732";
  var 9 m = "0.000011732";
  var 10 m = "0.000012732";
  var 11 m = "0.000013732";
  var 12 m = "0.000014732";

  slider.each(function() {

    value.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).prev().attr('value');
      $(this).html(value);
    });

    range.on('input', function() {
      $(this).next(value).html(this.value);
      document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = this.value * month;
    });
  });
};

rangeSlider();
```

```html
<script src='//production-assets.codepen.io/assets/common/stopExecutionOnTimeout-b2a7b3fe212eaa732349046d8416e00a9dec26eb7fd347590fbced3ab38af52e.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

<section>
  <span>SHA-256 (BTC)</span>
  <div class="chart">
    <canvas id="c1" width="900" height="200"></canvas>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="range-slider">
    <input class="range-slider__range" type="range" value="100" min="10" max="10000">
    <span class="range-slider__value"></span>
    <span>Ghs</span>
    <h4>Price: <span id="price"></span> BTC</h4>
  </div>

  <select class="month_select" class="classic">
  <option>Select contract length</option>
  <option value="1">1 Month</option>
  <option value="2">2 Months</option>
  <option value="3">3 Months</option>
  <option value="4">4 Months</option>
  <option value="5">5 Months</option>
  <option value="6">6 Months</option>
  <option value="7">7 Months</option>
  <option value="8">8 Months</option>
  <option value="9">9 Months</option>
  <option value="10">10 Months</option>
  <option value="11">11 Months</option>
  <option value="12">12 Months</option>
</select>
```

Comment: So I see a few problems. 

First, you are redefining the "slider" variable at the top of your rangeSlider() function and changing the type.

Second, your variable definitions are all over the place. JS will help you out via hoisting (as far as making sure variables are declared) but writing this kind of code is going to set you up for errors down the line.

Your description of what you want was a little confusing but you might accomplish what you desire by using jQuery onChange functions and having one function calculate what it needs to.

Comment: Your ":selected" selector string is also spaced incorrectly (there should not be a space between the colon and the word "selected" and might not work (though this could have been a copy and paste error for this post)).

Comment: Would you be able to change it and post it as an answer so I can mark this as answered

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need to basically watch things and see if they change, it should be something simple like:

```
var monthSelect_Selector = '.month_select';
var sliderRange_Selector = '.slider__range_Selector';

var valuesChangedFn = function() {
  var monthSelect_value = $(monthSelect_Selector).val();
  var sliderRange_value = $(sliderRange_Selector).val();

  // Do your calculations here and set whatever HTML you want to set

  // As far as setting the values of your slider manually, you might try to reinitialize 
  // whatever library you're using with a new set of values, rather than directly manipulate HTML
};

$(monthSelect_Selector + ', ' + sliderRange_Selector).change(valuesChangedFn);
```